# How can I use a bool and bool condition in a mustache template?

Tags: boolean, mustache

I am looking to use two conditions together to handle a display. If both a and b are true, then show something.

In JavaScript, we would write: `if (a && b) { ... }`

Moustache

```
{{#(one && two)}} // or #one && #two
  <p>foobar</p>
{{/(one && two)}}
```

JSON

```
{
  "one": "OK",
  "two": "Yes"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that

```
if (a && b) {
}
```

is the same as

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
    }
}
```

So you can write you Mustach template like this:

Moustache

```
{{#one}}
{{#two}}
  <p>foobar</p>
{{/two}}
{{/one}}
```